# Show that $M \times \left\{0,1 \right\}$ contains two connected components

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold (without boundary). Prove that $M \times \left\{0,1 \right\}$ contains two connected components, each of which is diffeomorphic to M.

I've addressed the problem when $M$ is connected. Could anyone give me ideas in the case that $M$ is disconnected? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely it isn't true if $M$ is disconnected? I might be being dumb, but if $M$ is (say) two points, then I think the product is four points, each of which is a connected component.

Comment: You seemed to forget that $M$ is a manifold.

Comment: Points are 0-manifolds (the reasoning is the same if $M$ is the disjoint union of two spheres)

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear but here I don't consider manifolds of dimension $0$

Comment: If $M$ is disconnected then not only $M\times\{0,1\}$, will have more than two connected components, but it is apparent that it will be impossible for any *connected* component to be *diffeomorphic* to $M$.

Comment: I think I got it. This statement doesn't hold with M being disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

$M\times\{0,1\}$ is diffeomorphic to $M\sqcup M$, so the number of path connected components of $M\times\{0,1\}$ is exactly twice as that of $M$.